# How do I append the UNIX command date to an echo statement

Tags: unix, date, echo

Basically I want to have the terminal output a message followed by the date and time, like "Hi, today is -dateandtime-".

So echo can accomplish the first bit, and date can accomplish the last, but only separately, how can I put them together (in one command) so they output together.

Like

echo hello there

-new command-

date

Does it, but not in one line. Is pipelining the answer?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This will do it:

```
 echo "Hi, today is $(date)"
```

Answer (score 19):

Date time will take in an arbitrary format string.

```
> date +"Hi, today is - %a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
  Hi, today is - Thu Feb 2 03:28: CET 2012
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo Hello there, today is `date`
```

You can also format the output of date using modifiers like:

```
echo Hello there, today is `date +%D`
```

See `man date` for a complete list of the modifiers.

Answer (score 4):

Backtick will do the trick:

```
echo "Hi, today is" `date`
```

Answer (score 2):

For this particular problem, mimisbrunnr's solution is the right way to go.  For the general question of how to append data to an echo, some common techniques are:

```
$ echo 'Hi, today is ' | tr -d '\012'; date
Hi, today is Wed Feb  1 18:11:40 MST 2012
$ echo -n 'Hi, today is '; date
Hi, today is Wed Feb  1 18:11:43 MST 2012
$ printf 'Hi, today is '; date
Hi, today is Wed Feb  1 18:11:48 MST 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
$ date +"Hi, today is - %Y%m%d%H%M%S"
Hi, today is - 20240209004703
```